# Logic of substituting in maximization problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, upper-lower-bounds

I assume in the following that all functions are real valued and defined on the real numbers or product spaces of the real numbers. Suppose one is given the following maximization problem: $$\max_{x,y} f(x,y)$$ such that $x+y=10$ (this is just an arbitrary constraint for the sake of an example). Suppose further that $f$ is given by $$f(x,y)=g(x)+y$$ for some function $g$. One can then also substitute the constraint equation to obtain the maximization problem $$\max_x g(x)+10-x.$$ If one finds a solution $x$ for this maximization problem, is this also a solution for the maximization problem above? If so, why is this the case?

More formally the idea should be: One wants to find elements of the set $$S:=\{(x,y) \ | \ x,y \in \mathbf{R} \wedge x+y=10 \wedge \forall p,q \in\mathbf{R}:f(p,q)\leq f(x,y)\}.$$ Suppose now $x_1$ maximizes $g(x)+10-x$ meaning that $x_1$ is an element of the set $$A:=\{x \ | \ x \in \mathbf{R} \wedge \forall z \in \mathbf{R}: g(z)+10-z \leq g(x_1)+10-x_1\}.$$ Then by setting $y_1:=10-x_1$ one obtains a pair $(x_1,y_1)$ that satisfies $$[\forall z \ g(z)+10-z \leq g(x_1)+10-x_1] \wedge [x_1 + y_1 = 10].$$ Now this implies that for all $(x,y)$ with $x+y=10$ we have $$g(x)+y=g(x)+10-x\leq g(x_1)+10-x_1=g(x_1)-y_1$$ which means that $(x_1,y_1)$ indeed maximizes $f$ under the constraint that $x_1+y_1=10$. Is this the correct reason for substitution of equations to work? A converse implication does not hold because one loses information about $y$, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer, just some thoughts**

You need to notice the feasible region. Here is an example (in a journal).

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\max_{x,\, y} ~ - (x - 5)^2 - y^2 \tag{1}\\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad 16x = y^2.
\end{align*}
The maximizer is $x = y = 0$.

Then consider the following:
$$\max_{x} ~ - (x - 5)^2 - 16x. \tag{2}$$
The maximizer is $x = -3$.

Actually, you should consider the following:
$$\max_{x \ge 0} ~ -(x - 5)^2 - 16x. \tag{3}$$

---

**Example 2**:

Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
 &\max_{x,\, y} ~ - (x - 5)^2 + 5\mathrm{e}^{y} + 5\mathrm{e}^{-y} \\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad x = 5\mathrm{e}^{y} + 5\mathrm{e}^{-y}.
\end{align*}
The maximizer is $x = 10, y = 0$.

Then consider the following:
$$\max_{x} ~ - (x - 5)^2 + x. $$
The maximizer is $x = 11/2$.

Actually, you should consider:
$$\max_{x\ge 10} ~ - (x - 5)^2 + x.$$
(*Note*: $5\mathrm{e}^{y} + 5\mathrm{e}^{-y} \ge 10$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.)

That is, we need to add the constraint for $x$.
But, what if the range of $x$ is hard to determine?
For example,
\begin{align*}
 &\max_{x,\, y} ~ - (x - 5)^2 - \left(\frac45 y + \sin y - 2\ln (1 + y)\right) \\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad 12x = \frac45 y + \sin y - 2\ln (1 + y).
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok so what I think is happening here is that the first constraint already implies that $x$ has to be non-negative which is a constraint that is not captured in the second maximization problem, right? This would also imply that my argument above is incorrect, since I tried to show that solving the 2nd problem gives a solution to the 1st, right? Could you tell me where my mistake is? I am really interested for a more formal reason that the substitution works/can be used.

Comment: @MaxH I think in your case, it is fine. I just pointed out something perhaps to be noticed. However, this is not an issue if we explicitly state $x \ge 0$ in Problem (1).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If I understand you correctly, my argument is correct for the example I gave above? I have never seen a justification for these sort of methods being discussed, which is why I am curious. I now wonder if there is a more general procedure that can do, which also solves your example. I feel like one would have to formulate the constraint also in terms of functions $h(x)$ and $g(y)$ and then respect the domains and ranges of those. With this in mind one could potentially create a similar argument to mine above.

Comment: @MaxH I think of another situation. Suppose we want to $\max_{x, y} f(x) + e^y + e^{-y}$ subject to $x = e^y + e^{-y}$. If we consider $\max_{x} f(x) + x$, what happen if the maximizer $x$ satisfies $x < 2$, as you know $e^y + e^{-y} \ge 2$ for all $y$? So, you need to explicitly state $x \ge 2$ in the original problem.

Comment: Well in this case the implication that the substitution problem gives a solution the original problem does not hold. As I said, I think in a more general setting, where the constraints are not being represented by functions that are real valued and bijective, one needs to respect the domains and ranges of the constraint functions.

Comment: But that is only a thought and I don't know if it is correct or whether there are more general results. I am just trying to generalize my approach in my question, which I hope is correct. Again, I only see this being applied and solved, never discussed why it works.

Comment: @MaxH I think so. Perhaps, someone can give you rigorous argument.

Comment: I hope so! But your examples already helped show something that I neglected, so it was helpful nevertheless. Also having feedback on my more formal approach above, which you provided, was helpful, so thanks.